# Problemas con maven en eclipse could not resolve archetype

Tags: java, maven

Estoy teniendo problemas al trabajar con maven tanto eclipse como netbeans.

Me aparece error al generar un proyecto:

> could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories

Os cuento lo que tengo por si algún paso esta mal pero estado revisando y no encuentro la manera de solucionarlo.

He descargado la carpeta en D y desde variable de entorno `MAVEN_HOME` llamo a la raíz `D:\apache-maven-3.3.9` y en path llamo a `maven_home`. En la configuración del propio eclipse `windows-preferences-archetypes-remote  http:// repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml`.

La verdad que he buscado bastante por internet pero no encuentro la solución para que pueda trabajar con maven.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

pregunta, ¿La red de tu conexión cuenta con alguna política restrictiva de trafico? Me suena a que probablemente algún firewall este bloqueando el trafico de  red a los repositorios Maven.

Intenta lo siguiente, desde eclipse:
Open Window > Preferences
Open Maven > Archetypes
Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the following:
Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
Description: maven catalog

Revisa configuración en parametros de conexión:

1) Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections. Coloca la dirección y puerto del proxy que uses.

Da una vuelta por esta pregunta: [Cannot create Maven Project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760961/cannot-create-maven-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: Voy a revisarlo porque trabajando con la version Mars2 de Eclipse me da problemas pero al trabajar con Juno que es una version mas antigua puedo trabajar sin problemas .Voy a revisar lo que me comentas porque puede ser problema de eso.Muchas gracias

Comment: Gracias por la contestacion puedo trabar sin problema era problema de red.